# How to access Cell from jQuery data tables from specific table row

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, datatables

I have a JFiddle that is able to recognise the table row and return the table data as required but need to return the last two cells of the row, which are write-able, modify and return modified values? How can I modify the jQuery as follows?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

    $('#button').click(function () {
        var ids = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
            return item[0]
        });
        console.log(ids)
        for(var i =0;i<table.rows('.selected').data().length;i++){
        alert(table.rows('.selected').data()[i] + ' row(s) selected');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f4bppa43/

Comment: @HenryDev yes Exactly

Comment: do you still want to have the headers: Start date and Salary ?

Comment: Yes Exactly @HenryDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pretty much does it after painstaking testing and experimenting!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

    $('#button').click(function () {
        var ids = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
            return item[0]
        });
        console.log(ids)
        for(var i =0;i<table.rows('.selected').data().length;i++){

        alert(table.rows('.selected').data()[i] + ' row(s) selected');
        }
    });
     var ids = table.rows('.selected').data()

     $('#button').click(function( row, data, index ) {
  row=table.rows('.selected');
  data=table.rows('.selected').data();
    if ( data[0] == "1,System Architect,Edinburgh,61,2011/04/25,$320,800" ) {
      alert($('td:eq(4)',row[1]).text());
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4bppa43/480/

Answer (score 1):

Based on original documentation there are a couple of ways to do this:

https://datatables.net/reference/type/cell-selector

1- By Id:

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 var data = table.cell('#cell-2-42').data();
```

2- By Class

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var cells = table.cells('.priority');
```

3- By Multiple selectors:

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 var cells = table.cells('.important, .intermediate');
```

Comment: @Adel MehrabanHow  would I map the cells to rows?

Comment: var rows = table.rows( { selected: true } ).indexes();

Comment: Sorry for the last comment:  https://datatables.net/blog/2015-09-11#Buttons-and-Select